# PHP check root of url

Tags: php, session, url

I am using below script to create sessions

```
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (
        false !== strpos($url,'home') || 
        false !== strpos($url,'display-job') || 
        false !== strpos($url,'search-results-jobs') ||
        false !== strpos($url,'find-jobs') ||
        false !== strpos($url,'edit-profile1') ||
        false !== strpos($url,'my-account/?myacount=1')
        ) 
        {
            $_SESSION['page_name'] = 'jobseeker';
        } 
    else {
        $_SESSION['page_name'] = 'employer';
    }
```

I can use the above script to check if someone is on one of the following sub pages but the problem is that i want to trigger a different session when someone is on the root of the webpage and I cant figure a way out.

Comment: Put `|| $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'` in the condition, or `want to trigger a different session when someone is on the root`, what condition? Also it might be easyier to check for `employer` routes and reverts to `jobseeker` by default rather then the opposite as your doing.

Comment: Thanks Loz, u have a point, I should do the other way round, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$url =  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$root_url =  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$arr_url = explode("/", $url);
unset($arr_url[sizeof($arr_url)-1]);
$new_url = implode("/",$arr_url);


if($new_url==$root_url)
{
    // do your work
}
```

Comment: Thanks Satish, this seems a bit complicated but will surely try this.